# Why I can not see the Email field for User object when using Object Manager?

Tags: object

I can not see the Email field on the object User while viewing it in Object Manager.

Here is an attached screenshot(I sorted by field name and the email is missing): 
[image: object manager email not found picture]

However if I am looking in the Schema Builder I am able to see it. See screenshot below(highlight in red): 
[image]

Comment: facing the same issue.. did you find a resolution?

Comment: No, performed the changes I had to do back then from the schema builder

Answer (score 1):

I have created a Salesforce Support Case to review this issue.
The answer I got was this one

> The field email is not viewable on the user object when using the field and relationship section of Object Manager. This is working as designed.
> The email field is a standard field with a unique metadata and is only viewable in Classic. This field is used to uniquely identify a user account across orgs when you create a user. You could also view this using schema builder since schema builder is also in Classic. I am unable to find any documentation that explains why this is designed that way...
> For whatever purpose you wish to view the details of email field in the User Object, you will need to switch to Classic to do this.
> What we can assure you is that the email field is accessible for workflows, look up relationships, formulas, Apex Code, Visualforce Pages, etc., as long as you have the necessary permission regardless if it is not viewable using the object manager of the Lightning Experience.

In addition, I have a workaround for how to see the Email field in the Lightning Experience. Since, most probably, this field is not shown due to a simple omission of this field in the page layout, the easiest way to see it is to

1. Click on any other field of the User standard object, say Email Encoding
   [image]
2. Then in the URL for Email Encoding, update 'EmailEncodingKey' to be 'Email'
   [image]
3. Result
   [image]